# Hibernate - Tomcat - SQL Server - Connection closed issue

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I've a webapp running on TOMCAT 7.0.5 - JDK 1.7 - and connecting to SQL Server 2012.

The hibernate version is 4.3.5. Browser used is IE 11.0.

The issue Is I have a webpage: A normal FORM submit (submit.jsp). It shows a readonly page (submitConfirm.jsp) and has two buttons.

1. Submit - Saves the application and redirects the page to the home page to start subscription again
2. Print - opens a new tab via javascript to print a PDF form that likely takes 2 to 5 seconds to render in a "new" tab.
3. The submit button is disabled by defualt and enabled only when user clicks on the PRINT Button. While the item is still rendering If someone clicks on Continue button - all actions perform well and at the I get both the print and subscriptions saved.
4. The next subscriptions entered would throw a http 500 error indicating the "Connection is already closed".
5. I use the Standard HibernateUtil paradigm to begin/end/commit/rollback transactions.
6. The models are all XML based (not entity decorator based).

For normal workflows where if the user waits till the PDF is rendered all is fine.
But If the user is pressing the button of continue - Seems there is an issue.

Attached is the screen-grab of the error is someone finds it useful provide some hints.
[image]

Based on the user feedback (the concerned method):

```
 public String reportSessionId(String userId) throws InfrastructureException {
    String sid = null;
    try {
        sid = (String) HibernateUtil.getSession()
                .getNamedQuery("com.ttsme.ims.model.IMSUser.reportSessionId")
                .setString("userId", userId).uniqueResult();
    }
    catch (HibernateException ex) {
        throw new InfrastructureException(ex);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sid;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me your IMUserDao.java page?

Comment: Do not have enough credits to post as ANSWER - but this is the following items I did

 My system uses a HIBERNATE FILTER (in web.xml) - all *.jsp goes through them (Filter mapping).

The issue was my JSP Page was committing the transactions where as it was supposed to be committed by the FILTER. 

Once I removed the HibernateUtil.commitTransaction() and allowed the FILTER to do the commit for my page (which it was doing arleady as all my *.jsp were to be passing thorugh it). This issue got away.